# .NET SqlDependency with many notifications vs. high rate polling?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqldependency

I have a small table (approx. 200 rows) which changes all the time (couple of times per second).
I was looking for a solution where i could receive notification from the database each time it changes, rather than polling it (let's say 5-10 times per second).

Moreover, i would like to receive only the changed rows each time and not fetching the whole table - i have found this rather difficult to implement this utilizing SqlDependency class.

Couple of things to take under consideration:

1. I do not have control over the changes in the table nor do i have the ability to receive the data other than using the database.
2. I intend to build a service which will broadcast the changes to my front servers

Is there a way to do this using SqlDependency?

What is the best practice given this case?

BTW: i am using SQL server 2012

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What type of application are you working with?

Comment: i intend to use windows service which will broadcast the changes to my from servers

Comment: Last time I worked with notifications they were pretty much useless. May have changed in the meantime (I worked with SQL Server 2005), but we went back to polling.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, useless as in `doesn't notify when changes occur` or `wasn't a solution to our problem`

Comment: @adrianm *useless* as in "would have solved our problems if it had worked reliably and not suddenly stopped notifying without any apparent reason".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SqlDependency will only notify you that a change occurred, and you'll have to re-read the entire table. It works well with a low rate of notifications. At a high rate, you have to consider that notifications have a significant cost. See [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) for more details how SqlDependency works. As you cans see, there is significant cost:

- setting up the notification (writing in sys.dm_qn_subscriptions and in SSB system tables)
- firing the notification (writing sys.dm_qn_subscriptions)
- delivering the notification (writes in SSB system tables, target queue)
- receiving the notification (writes in target queue, SSB system tables)

That's quite a few writes, the cost will add up quickly if you get notified constantly.

But the real question is how exactly do you want to react in the application to a constant rate of change? what do you want to know, that *something* changed? well, you know, it always does, anytime the application needs the data it better read the latest state, because it certainly changed. Polling does not make sense either. Sounds like what you really want is either [change tracking](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) or, more likely, a custom based [queue of changes](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) fed by the change originators.

Comment: Thank you! i edited the question due to your response. Will "change tracking" fulfill the goal?

Comment: Given what you have written, how can i receive notification from the database when something is changed? i have read about "change tracking" and it enables me to get the differences but not to get noticed when they occur so i still need to do polling ... Am i right?

Comment: You'll still have to poll the change tracking data, at the desired frequency. It will solve the problem of detecting *what* changed.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Is Service Broker External Activator which fires exe and this exe expose data to client an efficient for such case?