# How to listen database changes and retrieve them always

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have an application that needs to act whenever there is an insertion by other clients on the sql server database.How can I notify the change and retrieve them ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288434/how-to-monitor-sql-server-table-changes-by-using-c

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288434/how-to-monitor-sql-server-table-changes-by-using-c) already discusses about how can you be notified about SQL changes using [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) class. However, it is not just unicorns and rainbows, so you should also read these resource before pursuing this path:

**1) Consider polling** - check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660825/net-sqldependency-with-many-notifications-vs-high-rate-polling)

**2) Read the limitations** - check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588572/what-are-the-limitations-of-sqldependency) to see that there are lots of limitations

**3) Caching** using [SqlCacheDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), if you are using ASP.NET